# iphone - Detecting what type of simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, simulator

how can I detect whether I'm using iphone simulator or ipad simulator.
I'm using some 3rd party library to which I've to pass a parameter whether i'm using ipad or iphone. in order to test the app, i want to programatically detect whether i'm using iphone simulator or ipad simulator. is there any way to identify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] hasPrefix: @"iPad"]`

Comment: I found that if you're running a Universal Binary (or iPad only) on 4.3, then the above code works (e.g. [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] is iPad Simulator.  If however you are running an iPhone app on the iPad (e.g. when it displays with the 2x button) then  [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] is actually 'iPhone Simulator'.  This makes sense when you think about it!

Answer (score 5):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  // iPad code
}
else {
  // iPhone code
}
```